# Put 2 buttons div on my banner and center

Tags: html, css

I would like to put 2 buttons div (register and login) on my banner and center. However I think that I already have a problem with my blocks on my html ??

Here is an overview of my website in below.

screenshot:

[image]

My first problem is that I don't can to use the margin-left or margin-right to move my button "register" or "login" for center.

My problem comes perhaps from code HTML, Is it a problem with my blocks ? 
Here is my code HTML

```
<div class="my-banner">
    <img class="banner" src="images/slider.jpg"/>
    <div class="transparent"></div> 
    <a href="index.php"><img class="picture-logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="myButtonRegister"><a href="lolo.php">REGISTER</a></div>
      <div class="myButtonLogin"><a href="lolo.php">LOGIN</a></div>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="index.php">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a>
        <a href="#">NEWS</a>
        <a href="#">FAQS</a>
        <a href="#">RULES</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code CSS

```
.myButtonRegister{
  margin-top: 342px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;

}

.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.myButtonLogin{
  margin-top: 342px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;

}
```

Do you have an idea plase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `position:absolute` remove `margin-top` and give parent div to `height` and `position:relative`

```css
.my-banner{
  position:relative;
  height: 450px;
}
.btnBox{
position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 336px;
}
.myButtonRegister{

  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;

}

.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.myButtonLogin{

  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="my-banner">
    <img class="banner" src="images/slider.jpg"/>
    <div class="transparent"></div> 
    <a href="index.php"><img class="picture-logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btnBox">
            <div class="myButtonRegister"><a href="lolo.php">REGISTER</a></div>
      <div class="myButtonLogin"><a href="lolo.php">LOGIN</a></div>
      </div>

      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="index.php">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a>
        <a href="#">NEWS</a>
        <a href="#">FAQS</a>
        <a href="#">RULES</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a father box to your buttons and use `flex` to align your buttons. Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}

.container .subcontainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <button>Login</button>
    <button>Register</button>
  </div>
  <!--NAV-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code for good design and set maximum height & width image in banner no issues create for this type of design this is the right way.**

```css
.myButtonRegister{
  float: left;
  background-color: #C22312;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
.myButtonRegister a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.myButtonLogin{
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 48px;
  width: 168px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  font-family: 'Pridi', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 10px; 
  word-spacing: 0px;
}
.button-action {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-banner">
  <div class="banner-image">
    <img class="banner" src="images/slider.jpg"/>
      <div class="button-action">
        <div class="myButtonRegister"><a href="lolo.php">REGISTER</a></div>
        <div class="myButtonLogin"><a href="lolo.php">LOGIN</a></div>                    
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="transparent"></div> 
  <a href="index.php"><img class="picture-logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="index.php">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
        <a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a>
        <a href="#">NEWS</a>
        <a href="#">FAQS</a>
        <a href="#">RULES</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: waaaawwww thank you a lot. is there a possibility to put 0.5cm between the two buttons?